# How to delete subscriptions group in itunes connect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am in trouble, I made a test subscriptions group in iTunes connect, but now I cannot delete it. Is there any way to delete it?

Comment: you can see the following link of Apple Support which is as follows:-https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202039.                                                 Hope this link may help you :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer of you Swati Gautam, but the question is about iTunes connect, there I have made testing subscription group, but now I cannot delete that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to delete a Subscription Group, if there are no subscriptions in it.

---

If you have subscriptions within the Subscription Group, start by deleting the subscriptions first. You can find the `Delete This Subscription` text-button at the bottom of the subscription detail page.

When your Subscription Group is empty, a `Delete This Subscription` text-button would appear at the bottom of the Subscription Group's detail page. Clicking that should do the job.

Answer (score 3):

This does not currently seem possible.

From [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73951) on the apple developer forums:

> No, those are required in situ [on site] for historical reference and to help guard against duplicated/conflated references going forward.
>
> Feel free to file a feature request via the bug reporter link, below right, if deleting them is something you'd like to see in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In your app store connect Subscriptions：
You can see "Availability ?", it says: Only an Account Holder can remove.

Select the checkbox to make your subscription available on the App Store after approval. Only an Account Holder can remove an approved auto-renewable subscription from sale.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm, as I just figured this out! I believe this is because they want you to be sure of your actions so the Apple team made it a two step process.

First, you must go into the Subscription Details page. You probably won't see the **"Delete This Subscription"**. You do have the option when you're creating a new Subscription. However, once the Subscription has been approved, that option goes away.

Once on the Subscription Details view, you must first select the radio icon to **"Remove from Sale"**. Once you have confirmed and saved those changes, you will then have the **"Delete This Subscription"** text at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Here's information from the App Store Connect Help Guide.

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev636f037c8

**Remove an auto-renewable subscription from sale**.

Required Role: Account Holder. See Role permissions.

To remove your subscription from sale:

1. From the homepage, click My Apps, then select the app associated
   with auto-renewable subscription.
2. In the toolbar, click Features, and in the left column, click In-App
   Purchases.
3. Click on the subscription.
4. Under Availability, deselect Cleared for Sale to remove your
   subscription from sale. Confirm in the dialogue by clicking Removing
   from Sale.
5. Click Save

Apps in the Magazines and Newspaper category need at least one active auto-renewable subscription to be listed on the App Store. If your app is in the Magazines and Newspapers category and you wish to discontinue the only auto-renewable subscription in your app, you must switch to a different category and submit a new binary to App Store Connect. After that, you'll be able to remove the auto-renewable subscription from your app.

If you are unable to remove your subscription with the appropriate amount of lead time to provide the full amount of content through the duration of a customer’s subscription period, you should contact us.

If your app does not function without the discontinued auto-renewable subscription, remove your app from the App Store.

Answer (score -8):

- Go to Settings > USERNAME > iTunes & App Store.
- Tap your Apple ID located on the top of the screen.
- Tap View Apple ID. You will have to authenticate your Apple ID.
- Tap Subscriptions to view a list
- Tap the subscription that you want to cancel 
  It will display a blue check-mark once selected
- below everything is a red cancel subscription tap it

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the question was about deleting subscriptions groups in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the question is about iTunes connect, there I have made testing subscription group, but now I cannot delete that...

Comment: it's an answer for another question